# How slf4j replace org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder placed in sfl4j-api to real StaticLoggerBinder

Tags: java, classloader, slf4j

There are exist classes org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder, org.slf4j.impl.StaticMarkerBinder, org.slf4j.impl.StaticMDCBinder in slf4j api. But each binding to concrete logger should contain the same classes.

For example:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.java?av=f

and its log4j implementation:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.java?av=f

How java classloaders substitute it? Shouldn't here be an exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you extract the actual slf4j-api jar you'll notice that `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` is not actually included in the jar. SFL4J api is compiled against the class at build but it isn't actually included in the artifact. If you look at the source for `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` in the api module it has no implementation, all the public instance methods throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. This is ok, again because that class is excluded from the slf4j-api jar.

The classloader behaves normally and select the first version of `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` that is found when the class needs to be loaded. This will generally be from the first slf4j implementation jar that it listed on the classpath.

Note:
The `findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet()` is only used to warn that there are multiple bindings present on the classpath. It does not actually load any bindings.

Comment: Amazing. You make my evening !

Answer (score 1):

hm, good question as `slf4j` is suppose to not use runtime loading classes. It looks that uses classloader checks at startup in below method:

```
private static Set findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet() {
    // use Set instead of list in order to deal with  bug #138
    // LinkedHashSet appropriate here because it preserves insertion order during iteration
    Set staticLoggerBinderPathSet = new LinkedHashSet();
    try {
      ClassLoader loggerFactoryClassLoader = LoggerFactory.class
              .getClassLoader();
      Enumeration paths;
      if (loggerFactoryClassLoader == null) {
        paths = ClassLoader.getSystemResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
      } else {
        paths = loggerFactoryClassLoader
                .getResources(STATIC_LOGGER_BINDER_PATH);
      }
      while (paths.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL path = (URL) paths.nextElement();
        staticLoggerBinderPathSet.add(path);
      }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      Util.report("Error getting resources from path", ioe);
    }
    return staticLoggerBinderPathSet;
}
```

@Dev is right - `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` is included only in slf4j-api sources and not binaries - Including only in sources is simple trick for compile reasons. It is understandable that `findPossibleStaticLoggerBinderPathSet` is used only for logging purposes.